# What is the time complexity of an algorithm that calls a polynomial time algorithm?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis

I'm having a difficult time understanding time complexities of algorithm. I know that a polynomial time is of the form O(n^m) where m is a constant. Consider the following case where A is a list of elements:

```
Foo(A)
for each element a in A:
    for each element b in A-a:
        Polynomial-Time-Algorithm-Bar(A, a, b)
```

If **n** is the size of A,

1) Am I right in understanding that `Foo(A)` is also a polynomial time algorithm , because the function `Polynomial-Time-Algorithm-Bar` is called `(n-1)*n` times ?

2) When would an algorithm making calls to another polynomial time algorithm become exponential. I understand that if it has a running time of O(n^m) and m is variable and n is constant, then it would be exponential. Can you give me an example of such a case in the above example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume $n$ is the number of entries in array/set `A`.

1. Yes, since polynomials are closed against multiplication; specifically, $n(n-1) \cdot p(n)$ is always polynomially bounded as long as $p(n)$ is polynomially bounded.
2. As a consequence, the only way to achieve exponential running-time by calling a polynomial-time algorithm with parts of the original input is to call it exponentially often.

   **Example:**

   ```
   Foo(A)
     if |A| >= 2
       a = A[0]
       b = A[1]
       Polynomial-Time-Algorithm-Bar(A, a, b)
       Foo(A - a)
       Foo(A - b)
   ```

   The number of calls to `PTA-Bar` is [given by](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis)

   $\qquad\begin{align*}
     C(0) &= 0,\\
     C(1) &= 0,\\
     C(n) &= 2C(n-1) + 1, \qquad n \geq 2,
   \end{align*}$

   which [solves to](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2789/solving-or-approximating-recurrence-relations-for-sequences-of-numbers) 
   $C(n) = 2^{n-1} - 1$ for $n \geq 1$. Ergo, the running time of `Foo` is in $\Omega\bigl( 2^n \cdot p(n) \bigr)$ if `PTA-Bar` takes time $p(n)$.

Comment: Calling it on inputs of size 2^(n^([Ω](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#The_Knuth_definition)(1))) is another "way to achieve exponential running-time by calling a polynomial-time algorithm". ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer Add an answer?

Comment: @RickyDemer So it doesn't have to be a recursive algorithm to be an exponential? It would be great if you can elaborate with an answer.

Comment: @MadhavanRP You can always replace recursion with loops; I just found this example approachable and realistic. (Consider, for instance, `for i = 1 .. 2^n do PTA-Bar(...) end` -- trivial.)